# How to pass Today's Date as default value createFragmentContainer in argumentDefinitions

Tags: relay, relaymodern

I am using Relay Modern (V 1.7.0). We have requirement where we need to send today's date to our GraphQL API

```js
export default createFragmentContainer(
  UpcomingCampaigns,
  {
    Viewer: graphql`
    fragment UpcomingCampaigns_Viewer on Viewer  @argumentDefinitions(
      today: {type: "string", defaultValue:{field: "End_Date", value:"Need today's date here"}}
      }`
      )
```

So how do i pass today's date in value field ? doing ${new date()} don't work and giving error like Error: Parse error: Error: FindGraphQLTags: Substitutions are not allowed in graphql tags

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think it's possible, you should handle this on backend.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can pass variable as a string

```
  export default createFragmentContainer(
    UpcomingCampaigns,
     {
      Viewer: graphql`
      fragment UpcomingCampaigns_Viewer on Viewer  @argumentDefinitions(
      today: {type: "string", defaultValue:{field: "End_Date", value:"String"}}
     }`,
     variable:{
        value:  `${new date()}` 
     }
  )
```